# C# creating a hotkey that triggers function

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-interface, event-handling

I am currently working on a project and want to add a `KeyEventHandler` to my window, one that triggers a function on the press of a Key.

My problem however is, that when I want to add the handler like this

`testObject.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(doSomethingOnKeyPress);`

```
private void doSomethingOnKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e))
{
  if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.R)
  { 
   // do something
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error that the program can't convert `Forms.KeyEventHandler` into `Input.KeyEventHandler`.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction on this issue?

Comment: What type is your testObject? Apparently, you don't need to use constructor `+= new KeyEventHandler(doSomethingOnKeyPress)` if `doSomethingOnKeyPress` matches event handler signature. `testObject.KeyDown += doSomethingOnKeyPress` would work.

Comment: the test object i'm using for it is a TextBox

Answer (score 0):

I think you use wrong namespaces try to change

```
private void doSomethingOnKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e))
```

to

```
private void doSomethingOnKeyPress(object sender, Forms.KeyEventHandler e))
```

or get organized in the using section

Answer (score 0):

Changing namespaces should work, but I guess should be the other way round, namely

```
private void doSomethingOnKeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.R)
  { 
   // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're accidently mixing up the events KeyPress & KeyDown.

KeyPress & KeyDown are two different events, and therefore have different event handlers!

KeyDown should be:
testObject.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(doSomethingOnKeyPress);

Answer (score 0):

```
private void myClass(){
//doing something
}
private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.W){
    myClass();
    }
}*
```

*You Can Use "W" For Example You Can Make D A Or Whatever you want*

**Edit: Forget the above answer the problem is "doSomethingOnKeyPress" is a keypress function but code is trying to implement it on a KeyDown event as in: "testObject.KeyDown +="**